# Сортировка записей по кол-ву вхождений SQL

Tags: sql

Народ, подскажите как зделать сортировку по кол-ву вхождений.
У меня есть 2 таблицы, одна допустим tags{id,objid,name} вторая objects{id,title,text};
У каждной записи objects можить быть любое кол-во разных привязок под ид(так как теги);
Использую запрос:

> SELECT o . *  FROM `tags` AS t,
> `objects` AS o WHERE (t.name LIKE
> '%something1%'OR t.name LIKE
> '%something2%' OR...OR t.name LIKE
> '%somethingX%')AND t.objid = o.id

но в результате нада убить похожие строки(т.к. дублируються) и отсортировать по кол-ву вхождений DESC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT o.id, o.title, o.text, count(*) as qty FROM tags AS t, objects AS o WHERE (t.name LIKE '%something1%'OR t.name LIKE '%something2%' OR...OR t.name LIKE '%somethingX%')AND t.objid = o.id
group by o.id, o.title, o.text
order by qty desc
```

[Группировка](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_group_by_clause.html)

Answer (score 1):

DISTINCT -- фильтрует по уникальным данным

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
```

Comment: да, DISTINCT убивает повторы но мне еще надо отсортировать по кол-ву вхождений

Comment: Тогда GROUP BY, - группирует по уникальным значениям